# Protect system disk from attaching to another machine

Tags: mount, encryption, security

I have a device (*Raspberry PI 3, Orange PI 5*) with SSD as main disk, running under *Ubuntu 22.04*.
This device should be autonome, i.e. autimatically reboot and autorun some services.
There is some sensitive data, which is accessed by those services during acting (including those services itselves).
Is there any option to protect its disk from mounting to another machine and getting those data? If person has physical access to the device and can get the disk.
Considering user password is protecting the access to the original device on normal running.
So my aim to deny access to the data if disk is attached to another machine.

Comment: Which disto and version of Linux are you running? Which version of RPi hardware do you have? Is the RPi connected to any LAN using Ethernet or WiFi? If so which (Ethernet or Wifi)? Add these information [to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506482/edit).

Comment: The only way to secure this setup would have been, at installation, to encrypt the disk fully.  Rule 1 of IT Security: if anyone gets access to the physical hardware, you have a larger problem.  The only way to *mitigate* data access is to encrypt the disk at installation time with full disk encryption on the data.  That requires an on-boot password though so on reboot it can't just 'autostart'.  And unfortunately you can't otherwise "prevent a disk from being mounted" on any other machine.  Short of encryption of the data.

Comment: If someone can break into your room and take the SSD what is stopping them to take the Raspberry Pi along with the SSD? That way the bad guys will have your Raspberry Pi, your SSD and your sensitive data.

Comment: The goal is to protect the device with being reverse engineered. The device is mounted on the client`s location.
So, the option with manual boot password is impossible. 
In fact I should protect only several folders with sensitive data. In original OS this is achieved with permission restrictions, so i can autorun my apps under specified login with granted access to those files. But obviously, this will not protect from accessing files if disk will be mounted on anothe machine.